# In responsive mode css is taking from this file , automatically generating this file in root folder/media/css directory in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

File name is
`media/css/0e0a33446067e9918f5a6f676ebf323f.css`

I dont want to generate this file auto, What i have to do , please suggect me,

Thank You

Jagdish

Comment: why dont you want that? its better to compress and use css. Your site will load faster..

Comment: yes i agree, but while finding that required class in this file , its able to find that css property, so, what to do.

Comment: Oh. You are trying to hide some property of css you added in site from others???

Comment: yup, actullay slider height in response mode want to make auto, its already auto only , in this merge file that class is creating auto with having perticular height, so

Comment: First set merge css files to No. Check the issue persists. If so, make the width auto important in css. Then try.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this in admin panel

Navigate to

> admin > configuration > Developer > CSS Settings > Merge CSS Files

set this as **no**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to `System > Configuration` and find **Advance** section on your left.

Then click on **Developer** section and then **Css Setings** section.

Now set **Merge CSS Files** to **No**.

You are done.